# Too many requests - instabot.py

Tags: python, automation, virtual-machine

I have an issue with the script that I run to share posts on Instagram. The script works fine on my machine but when I ran it on a VM with OS ubuntu 16.04-LTS, it throws an error with too many requests and the error is as follows:

[image]

I think the problem is with the network, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username = username, password = password)
bot.upload_photo('img', caption='caption')
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how I can fix this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer that can help someone in the future:

After some research, I found that you should run `cd /home/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/api` and it should work for you. If not, find your own path using these two commands `pip list -v` and `pip show`. Hope this helps!

Edit the file `api.py` then comment from lines 559 to 585 but try not to make a lot of requests to not be blocked.

Answer (score -1):

It means you are sending too many request to the site. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

I would suggest using a retry-strategy to try again after a given amount of time.
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html

Comment: I know this but the script works fine on my machine so the problem in the virtual machine and the script share 1 post each hour so there is a sleep time